# How does fight club counter Nietzsche?

Tags: nietzsche, art

So it seems obvious to me the fight club critiques nietzsches school of thought. However, since it is a work of art I worry I may have missed all the points it makes. Can someone enlist them?

The director intends for this interpretation: https://youtu.be/2ykcUuZg9hI (minute 22)

Comment: what makes you think that the movie / book has anything to do with nietzsche?

Comment: It's a popular pop culture take as well: https://youtu.be/GYQGRRW8QvE

Comment: @DennisKozevnikoff i edited the question

Comment: i have watched fight club, but not your link. there's a complicity to it in fight club, if iirc. so the characters are all too ironically everything (hyper masculine, e.g.) to really fit in with nietzsche's arrogance

Comment: read [this](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/abs/nietzsche-as-german-philosopher/nietzsches-conception-of-irony/9097AAB65647F4C81DDCDED026936D32)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This site is for discussing established philosophical ideas and texts, what you are asking for is basically an original essay - because how can you expect an answer to exhaust all the points made in a work of art? That's a subjective judgement. See [PSE guide on How To Ask A Good Question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Likely this is why your answer has already recieved a 'close' vote.

The resonances with Nietzsche's work have been widely noted. Here are some example essays grabbed at random:

- [Fight Club & Nietzsche: Overcoming Emasculation](https://panzerknacker.substack.com/p/fight-club-and-nietzsche-overcoming), Bob Doyle.
- [The Philosophy of Fight Club: Tyler Durden as the Embodiment of
  Nietzsche’s Morality](https://monica-lin.me/templates/documents/Philosophy-Essay---Fight-Club--Nietzsche.pdf) (PDF link), Mae Lin
- [Mankind, muscles and memories: How does Fight Club provide a
  Nietzschean critique of the concept of the Übermensch?](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/340661470_Mankind_muscles_and_memories_How_does_Fight_Club_provide_a_Nietzschean_critique_of_the_concept_of_the_Ubermensch), T Powell.
- ["Fight Club", Self-Definition, and the Fragility of Authenticity](https://www.jstor.org/stable/23785885)
  William Irwin.

Authenticity is a big theme. Ed Norton's charachter relates to the Last Man, and fear of decay of Western civilisation into mediocrity, and lifelessness. People particularly relate Fight Club's themes to On The Geneology of Morals. It's a big topic. I don't think Fight Club does 'counter' Nietzsche. You could say it explores some of his ideas in a modern context. I don't think it contradicts any of them, or even really critiques them. Durden is a fairly visceral image of an ubemensch, impulsively reforming the world towards his own values. Basically a terrorist. But I don't think Nietzsche would have dissapproved, quite the opposite.

Read some essays, and try to ask something more specific.

Comment: Thanks I'll try to adhere better